# Package Visibility Issue in Java

Tags: java, terminal, package

DETAILS :

I am trying to build a java project from command line with the following directory structure :

```
proj/
    Makefile
    Main.java
    lexer
    tokens
    ast
    interpreter
    lib
```

QUESTION :

I assume that Main.java has access to all `classes`, `enums`, `interfaces`, and `annotations` of all the four folders. But, if I want to use the `enum` in `tokens` package, is there any way to do so ? By way, I mean what access specifiers should I use to fulfill my use case ?

LINKS which I used before asking this question :

-https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

-https://medium.com/virtuslab/on-the-missing-package-private-or-why-java-is-better-than-kotlin-in-this-regard-4a1c9ecbe40c#:~:text=The%20default%20access%20modifier%20in,classes%20in%20the%20same%20package.&text=It%20was%20hardly%20used%20and,fields%20when%20inheritance%20was%20needed.

-http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c694/lectures/Visibility/visibility.html

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Main can import from packages and main is in default package.

Comment: *I assume that Main.java has access to all classes, enums, interfaces, and annotations of all the four folders* ... wrong assumption. Any class only has access to the classes in the same package, or to whatever it imports from other packages. Beyond that, please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. This all depends on what package names you used where and so on. Also note: why are using a MAKEFILE to build java stuff? What you are showing here looks like something from 2005. You should rather use gradle (or maybe maven) as build tool instead.

Comment: In other words: there are plenty of things that are (or feel) plain wrong in what you outline here. It seems you really don't much about java yet, but still you intend to work on something that is already quite big. My recommendation: step back. Get a good book or tutorial, and work through much simpler examples first. You are trying to build a whole garden shed, but you kinda don't have any clue how to hold a saw or what that hammer thing is good for. That is most likely not going to work out for you.

Comment: @GhostCat I forgot to write that on importing it does have access. My reason for using a makefile is that I want to learn about GNU Make. I use Maven for my projects (usually) and gradle when working with Android. And as for a book on Java, I've read and now am attempting a project. Thanks though, for your help. It'll help other users who read this later.

Comment: So you are studying computer science history (or why else try to use make with a java project) ;-) ... okay, seriously: the fact that you want to use make doesn't prevent you from using a default, standard **file system layout** for your project. You should make sure that ALL your java classes sit in a package (have a package statement in the source file, and sit in the corresponding directories). And you should structure your project, see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using java8 and before:

1. `Main` will not have access to all classes and enum by default
2. `Main` will have access to classes and enums defined within `Main.java`
3. A method in `Main` will have access to inner classes and enums
4. `Main` will have access to classes and enums defined as `public` in other packages
5. `Main` will have access to classes that it is extending in other packages(they should be atleast protected)

Similar access policy will be followed for other classes too. (Main has nothing special)

Please refer

1. [Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
2. [Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html)

Comment: @AritroShome See my comment on the question itself.

Comment: @Horse I am using Java14.0.0.1 FYI

Comment: @AritroShome, i assume you are interested in module related changes. If you have have all your classes within a single module, visibility for your class to other classes within the module will be same as pre-module era. If you are looking at ways to expose your public interface to consumers of your module, then please look into `open` feature. If you are using other modules, then `requires` might help. My knowledge in limited on these topics and may not be able to help with practical use cases.

Comment: @Horse thanks a lot! Modules are great but for pet projects I'll stick to this layout with some other changes which GhostCat specified